# Powershell-MS Word docx table to csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I've looked for several solutions regarding this as I'm still new to powershell, but there is this same kind of code everywhere. My problem is that it doesnot output all the contents of the word table to csv in the right format. Only one single last column data is output to the csv file. I can't understad where I am wrong. Please help me out.

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$filename = 'path to file'
$outputfile= 'path to file'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$Table = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$TableCols = $Table.Columns.Count
$TableRows = $Table.Rows.Count
for($r=1; $r -le $TableRows; $r++) {
    for($c=1; $c -le $TableCols; $c++) {
        #Write-Host $r "x" $c
        $content = $Table.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text
        Write-Host $content
        $content | Out-File $outputfile
    }
}
$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
```

I've tried using `Export-Csv` but it gives me length even with adding `-noTypeInformation` there is no result.
Also how can I get a csv file created dynamically, instead of having to create a new empty csv file always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code currently outputs every single cell contents to the file individually.
Creating a cvs from a Word table like this is doable, but you need to capture the cell contents for each row in an array variable first and join the elements with a comma.
Then output the row.

For safety, quote every cell value so that fields having a comma inside do not make for a mis-aligned file afterwards.

Another snag is that Word appends each cel value from a table with control characters `0x0D` and `0x07`, so you need to remove those aswell.

Try

```
$objWord     = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$filename    = 'D:\Test\blah.docx'
$outputfile  = 'D:\Test\blah.csv'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$Table = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$TableCols = $Table.Columns.Count
$TableRows = $Table.Rows.Count
# this gets the list separator character your local Excel expects when double-clicking a CSV file
$delimiter = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator

for($r = 1; $r -le $TableRows; $r++) {
    # capture an array of cell contents
    $content = for($c = 1; $c -le $TableCols; $c++) {
        # surround each value with quotes to prevent fields that contain the delimiter character would ruin the csv,
        # double any double-quotes the value may contain,
        # remove the control characters (0x0D 0x07) Word appends to the cell text
        # trim the resulting value from leading or trailing whitespace characters
        '"{0}"' -f ($Table.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text -replace '"', '""' -replace '[\x00-\x1F\x7F]').Trim()
    }
    # output this array joined with the delimiter, both on screen and to file
    $content -join $delimiter | Add-Content -Path $outputfile -PassThru
}
$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objDocument)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Using the file you have made available, the output CSV (opened in Excel) looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works, now I know what I was missing. Regarding the control characters, you are replacing them will null type but by this the space between words (I have a sentence as one of the cell contents) is also getting removed.

Comment: @HAH Ah, didn't notice that. I have now anchored the replace to the end of the text in the cell.

Comment: Also when the content is in double quotes "data" the format gets messed up from that data till the end of the file. It is copied in one single column with , which is the csv format we get in console output. To escape the " " maybe I should use just replace with null. Another major issue is Add-Content gives an error randomly skipping 1-2 rows of data saying: ```Stream was not readable```. Out-File doesn't seem to work here, any alternative you could suggest?

Comment: @HAH I cannot reproduce any of that. Perhaps you are opening the csv in Excel by simply double-clicking the file? In that case, your Excel may not use the comma as default field delimiter, but maybe the semi-colon (`;`). This is a system locale (language) setting. Try exporting something from Excel to CSV, open in notepad to check what delimiter it uses, and if that is not the comma, change `$content -join ','` to join the fields with that character. As for `Stream was not readable`, I cannot see your original Word document, so it is not possible for me to try with the table you have in there.

Comment: @HAH I have edited the code to output the csv file using the delimiter character your local Excel expects, so double clicking the resulting CSV should open correctly in EXcel

Comment: pls take a look at this sample input and output for your solution: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_9Qabzj1JBZLX7RUYBDrBkTx36rq_Rnl?usp=sharing

Comment: 5 out of 10 times `Add-Content` throws 2 kinds of errors randomly- `stream not readable` or `proccess can't acces file...because it is being used by another process`. I have looked it up and it seems it's a common issue. I tried using `Ecport-Csv` but it returns length even though `$content` is object. Using `Out-File` with '-append` the format is ruined with everything in a single column.

Comment: @HAH The problem was indeed the cell value `Status "pending"` which contains double-quotes. I have now edited my answer to double any possible double-quote characters in a cell value to also make that value correct for csv. I have inserted a screenshot so you can see the resulting file I get on my computer (using PowerShell 5.1 and MS Office Pro 2016)

Comment: Sry to respond this late, your answer helped me out a lot. Thank you!